# Java 8 | Finding Map Entry with highest size of value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have model Person[city, name]. I have collected them in Map And Grouped them by city. I need to trace the city that has most no of person staying there and return only that entry as part of Map. I'v tried and also it is working but i was wondering is there any better way of doing.

```
Comparator<Entry<String, List<Person>>> compareByCityPopulation =
        Comparator.comparing(Entry<String, List<Person>>::getValue, (s1, s2) -> {
            return s1.size() - s2.size();
        });

HashMap mapOfMostPopulatedCity = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity), m -> {

            Entry<String, List<Person>> found = m.entrySet().stream().max(compareByCityPopulation).get();

            HashMap<String, List<Person>> hMap = new HashMap<>();
            hMap.put(found.getKey(), found.getValue());

            return hMap;
        }));

System.out.println("*City with Most no of people*");
mapOfMostPopulatedCity.forEach((place, peopleDetail) -> System.out.println("Places " + place + "-people detail-" + peopleDetail));
```

Please Suggest how can we write better in java 8.

Comment: if your lambda is more than 2-3 lines there it needs **refactoring.**-wise programmer

Comment: mapOfMostPopulatedCity always has 1 element. Why do you use HashMap?

Comment: @Twister what else can be used in-place of this? Need to represent key , value.

Comment: Map.Entry<String, List<Person> result = persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity)).entrySet().stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size()))
.orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After getting the max map entry, you have to convert that into a map which has a single entry. For that you can use `Collections.singletonMap()`

```
Map<String, List<Person>> mapOfMostPopulatedCity = persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity)).entrySet().stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValue().size()))
    .map(e -> Collections.singletonMap(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
```

With Java9 you can use `Map.of(e.getKey(), e.getValue())` to build the map with a single entry.

Comment: With Java 9, you could also use `.map(Map::ofEntries)`, as the input is already a `Map.Entry`.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose if you have an list of persons

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Then first group By them based on city and then get the Entry with max values in list `max` will return `Optional` of `Entry`, so i won't make it complicate i will just use `HashMap` to store the result if it present in optional or else will return the empty `Map`

```
Map<String, List<Person>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

     persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getCity)) //group by city gives Map<String,List<Person>>
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(value->value.getValue().size())) // return the Optional<Entry<String, List<Person>>>
    .ifPresent(entry->resultMap.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue()));

//finally return resultMap
```